# QMainWindow Titlebar Style Change

Tags: qt

I am beginner and just began learning Qt.
When I created a new project, it has mainwindow.ui, mainwindow.cpp, mainwindow.h, and main.cpp.
I want to change color of title bar of mainwindow, but i can't find title bar in design mode.
How to get this done?
Thank you.

Comment: Not an easy thing to do I would say https://forum.qt.io/topic/46620/customize-titlebar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it via `QWidget` with `SIGNALS` and `SLOTS`.

Here example how to do it: **https://evileg.com/en/post/156/**